# Journey Email not sending even if user enter the journey. Still in Queued status and restarted the triggered send.

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, triggered-send

This is my journey and the criteria and the entry data. I have changed this up so much.  Just want to make sure I am doing the right thing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In Journey Builder, there is a tab at the top titled "History." You can check that to error messaging. Also, if the person is going through the Journey, but not sending, you should also check the email. If there is an error in the email, then it would send. Ex. if the email is trying to pull data via AMPScript that isn't there. Or the record in the DE doesn't have a valid SubscriberKey.

Comment: The AMPscript is working.  It will not even send a test send.

Comment: What do you get when you do a send preview of your email with the entry event DE?